# Search empty folders using CLI & AQL query

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

How I can search for empty folders in my repo using Jfrog CLI + AQL query ?

Answer (score 0):

Found your question looking for the same answer.  Lower in my google result was this JFrog KB posting created recently (since you posted the question).  https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/empty-folder-clean-up/